# Flask + Selenium application on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, flask, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver, zappa

Encountered several problems deploying with `zappa` `flask` application with `selenium`, using `chromedriver` and `headless_chromium`.

Deployment goes well right utill the end, when it gives 502 error. `zappa tail` reveals the following exception:

```
: WebDriverException
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 580, in lambda_handler
  return LambdaHandler.lambda_handler(event, context)
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 245, in lambda_handler
  handler = cls()
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 139, in __init__
  self.app_module = importlib.import_module(self.settings.APP_MODULE)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/tmp/lambda-selenium/src/main.py", line 29, in <module>
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('/tmp/lambda-selenium/bin/headless-chromium', chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "/tmp/lambda-selenium/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
  self.service.start()
  File "/tmp/lambda-selenium/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
  self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/tmp/lambda-selenium/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
  % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /tmp/lambda-selenium/bin/headless-chromium unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

As far as i remember6 when this error is encountered locally it is easily fixed by installing some missing packages. But is it the case with Lambda? And if it is, then how do I install them on Lambda?

Honestly, I've ran out of all ideas what might be the case. I deployed using this two guides:

1) [Deploying flask on Lambda with zappa.](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-create-a-serverless-service-in-15-minutes-b63af8c892e5)

2) [Deploying selenium on Lambda (with no API)](https://engineering.21buttons.com/crawling-thousands-of-products-using-aws-lambda-80332e259de1)